# Cannot Update SQL data in Shiny + RMySQL by actionButton()

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I am trying to construct a form in Shiny, to let my coworker maintains data in MySQL.

My RMySQL works, I can use `dbSendQuery(MySQLCon, Query)`,
  but if I want to use `actionButton()` to `UPDATE TableName SET Colname = 'Value' WHERE ID = 'ID'` information to database,
  It can't work, and it also shows no warning.

And if I directly execute for example `UpdateMySQL(DataTableName, "DayBir", "1989/06/04", "A001")`, mysql will UPDATE, but it will have a `warning : "Closing open result sets"`

Would you please help me to confirm is there any reactive expression is illegal ?

Code **ui.R**:

```
# define UI
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  # I add some js and css here for login mechanism by https://gist.github.com/withr/9001831
  # so if I want to use observe()
  # I should put observe() in the observe() which for login
  # and it will report error

  title = "Shiny Demo",

  # mainPanel
  uiOutput("MainUI")
))
```

Code in **server.R**:

```
# Load Data loading R
library(RMySQL)

MySQLCon = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 host = "localhost",
                 db = "DB",
                 user = "Usr",
                 password = "PW")
DataTableName = "Data"

DataInput = dbReadTable(MySQLCon, DataTableName)

# turn off connection
Allcons = dbListConnections(MySQL())
for (MySQLCon in Allcons) {
  dbDisconnect(MySQLCon)
}

UpdateMySQL = function(DataTableName, ColName, UpdateValue, UpdateIDSubj) {
  library(RMySQL)
  MySQLCon = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                   host = "localhost",
                   db = "DB",
                   user = "Usr",
                   password = "PW")
  Query = paste('UPDATE', DataTableName, ' ', # name of table in db
                  'SET', ColName, '="', UpdateValue, '" ', 
                  'WHERE IDSubj ="', UpdateIDSubj, '";', sep = "")
  dbSendQuery(MySQLCon, Query)

  # turn off connection
  Allcons = dbListConnections(MySQL())
  for (MySQLCon in Allcons) {
    dbDisconnect(MySQLCon)
  }
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # Authenticate
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      # KeyIn UI
      source("./KeyIn/KeyIn.R",  local = TRUE, encodin = "utf-8")

      # main
      output$MainUI = renderUI({
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(id = 'TabSet',
            tabPanel(title = "Key In Data",
              numericInput("KeyInChoice", "Choice Row You Want", value = 1,
                min = 1, max = dim(DataInput)[1], step = 1),
              uiOutput("KeyIn")),,
            tabPanel(title = "Raw Data",
              dataTableOutput("TableInput"))
          )
        )
      })

      output$TableInput = renderDataTable({
          DataInput
        }, option = list(orderClasses = TRUE))

    } # else show nothing
  })
})
```

Code in **KeyIn.R**

```
output$ApplyKeyIn = renderUI({
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3,
        # Subj ID
        textInput("IDSubj", "Subj ID",
                value = reactive({
                       if (is.null(input$KeyInChoice)) {
                       return("NULL")
                        } else {
                      return(isolate({ DataInput$IDSubj[input$KeyInChoice] })) }
                     })())
      ),
      column(width = 3,
        # Birthday
        dateInput("DayBir", "Birthday",
                    value = reactive({
                               if (is.null(input$KeyInChoice)) {
                       return("NULL")
                        } else {
                      return(isolate({ DataInput$DayBir[input$KeyInChoice] })) }
                         })(),
                    max = DateNow, format = "yyyy/mm/dd", language = "zh-TW")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 12,
        # Send
        actionButton("KeyInSend", "Send")
      )
    )
  )
})

# listening to edit data
KeyInUpdate = reactive({
  if (input$KeyInSend == 0) {
    return()
  }

  input$KeyInSend

  isolate({
    IDSubj = input$IDSubj
    DayBir = input$DayBir
    UpdateMySQL(DataTableName, "DayBir", DayBir, IDSubj)
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how your Shiny app should work. The message 'warning : "Closing open result sets"' will not be shown if you use the following:     temp<- dbSendQuery(ch, query_string)
    dbClearResult(temp)
    dbDisconnect(ch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem by updating data from API's.

My workaround was to use reactiveValues() and using eventReactive() functions.

```
x <- reactiveValues()
y <- eventReactive(x) {<code>}
```

And how it worked out for me was, everytime x updated anywhere in the code, y would change as well with new x passed to it.